# Learning C#, simple tutorial required

Tags: c#

I've only just recently begun coding in general, I do have some background experience in it, but I've started learning C#. I believe one of the major mile stones of learning any programming language in the beginning is understanding if/else statements.

so if someone can write me this bit of code it would really help me understand a lot about this language.

I'd like to see the following happen:

First, on my command prompt, a message shows. "Hello, what is your name?"
If name = Chris, then "Hello Chris!"
Else output = "You're not Chris!"

To be perfectly honest I'm not sure how easy it is to accomplish this with just the cmd prompt using C#, but this would be a big deal to me, so thank you for any and all help you can offer me!

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong? Post your code as well as any error / unexpected results.

Comment: If you're having trouble with the code. Post some pseudocode that you think the program flow should be in. And then slowly flesh out the program from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create a console application in visual studio, your code would look something like this:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, what is your name?");
    var name = Console.ReadLine();
    if (name == "Chris")
        Console.WriteLine("Hello Chris!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("You're not Chris!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much paq! That's exactly what I was looking for! I was trying to figure out how to allow a program in cmd prompt to allow input, and thats perfect!

Comment: After playing with this a little bit, I noticed that as soon as you enter your input the CMD prompt returns your output and then closes itself.

How do I make the CMD prompt stay and not close itself?

Again I really appreciate the help, You've really opened a door for me!

Comment: just add `Console.Read()` before the last curly brace.  `Console.Read*` is a blocking method.  It stops execution of the application until its satisfied.  With `ReadLine` it waits for a carriage return, with `Read` it waits for any single character, then it continues, in this case, closing the application.